# Jquery SlideUp , close but don't show effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideup

I want use **slideUp** with jquery , for close div i use **slideUp** , but close div happend in one second and don´t show really this effect

**My script it´s this :**

```
jQuery("#web_header_info_show_close").click(function() {

jQuery("#web_header_info_show").slideUp(2000);

});
```

The case i try modificate all time the time but always get the same , and if i change the time inside function and put more time , the effect continue don´t show and close in one second the div , i don´t know if it´s because  use click function , but i think don´t must be a problem for works well slideUp

Thank´s for the help , Regards

**UPDATE INFOR :**

**YOU CAN SEE DEMO HERE :** https://jsfiddle.net/gzdjdz25/

Comment: Without a working example, we can't really help with this problem, your code is valid, so any problems will be situational based on things other than what's visible here.

Comment: Can you please post a fiddle (http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Without a code sample, there is not much we can do. Try changing to 'slow', instead of 2000 in brackets and let us know if the result is still the same.

Comment: HTML? build a demo in jsfiddle please.

Comment: You can see demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/gzdjdz25/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `min-height:100px;` use `height:100px;` instead.

```
#web_header_info_show{
position:relative;
width:100%; 
height:100px;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:14px;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:red;
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gzdjdz25/1/

Comment: Good one! The issue was in overlapping.